# JNI_CreateJavaVM() terminates with exit code 1

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, jnienv

I'm trying to call a Java method from C++ using JNI. To do that I've installed `jdk1.7.0_51`, linking against `jdk1.7.0_51\lib\jvm.lib`, including `jdk1.7.0_51\include` and `jdk1.7.0_51\include\win32`. using the following code in Visual Studio 2012 I tried to create a Java vm object - but the function always terminates my application with exit code 1 (the function doesn't return 1: my program terminates completly and sends the exit code 1).

```
#include <iostream>
#include "jni.h"

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
  JNIEnv* env = nullptr;
  JavaVM* jvm = nullptr;
  JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
  JavaVMOption options[2];
  options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.";
  options[1].optionString = "-DXcheck:jni:pedantic";  
  vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
  vm_args.nOptions = 2;
  vm_args.options = options;
  vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE; // remove unrecognized options
  int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**) &env, &vm_args);
  std::cout << "This code is never reached" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**OS:** Windows 7 (x64)

**Compiler:** Visual Studio 2012 (x86/Win32 Project)

**Java VM:** jdk1.7.0_51, i586 (should be ok in my opinion, because I'm compiling for x86 - otherwise linkage with jvm.lib wouldn't work)

I've already tried to using both: `jdk1.7.0_51\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll` as well as `jdk1.7.0_51\jre\bin\Server\jvm.dll` - with the same result (I'm not entirely sure what the difference is though).

Any ideas & suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Using static linking**

1. remove the `jvm.dll` from your project directories. The dll must be loaded from it's original location, as it seems that other DLLs are involved, found by references.
2. Set the `PATH` environement variable to start with the folder of a JRE `jvm.dll`. And don't use the `"c:\folder with space in name"` notation (that is surrounding the path with `double quotes`). Just use `set path=c:\folder with space in name;%PATH%`. That mistake made my previous attempts worthless.

**Using dynamic linking.**

1. remove the `jvm.dll` from your project directories. The dll must be loaded from it's original location, as it seems that other DLLs are involved, found by references.
2. Drop `jvm.lib` from your project configuration
3. Use `LoadLibrary`, with the full path for jvm.dll (escape '\' or use '/')
4. Use `GetProcAddress` for "`JNI_CreateJavaVM`"
5. Make sure to use a proper `typedef` for the function pointer (use `JNICALL` as calling convention)

Patching your code with above steps makes my VS2012/Seven64/x86Debug/JDK1.6 project to output "This code is never reached" (with ret == `JNI_OK`)

Comment: Thanks - it works this way. My Problem was most likely to copy the dll to the project directory. Instead of copying setting the PATH variable to `jdk1.7.0_51\jre\bin\client` solved it (even with using the .lib & .h files - without `LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress`).

Comment: Thanks to you for the comment. Made me try again. Will update.